# Move SafeArgs in multi module project

Tags: android-safe-args

I im working on modularizationing android project.

I im using Navigation Component library.

I have main nav_graph.xml in :app module.

I want to move generated SafeArgs files to modules directories.

I didnt add `androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin` plugin to modules, except :app module.

I already move one testing generated args file into ordering module by gradle script after `generateSafeArgs` task finished. But my IDE cant see it in code. Everybody knows why IDE cant see my moved file?

Answer (score 0):

SafeArgs files are generated automatically so changes you make to them likely won't be reflected.
You'll need to add the safeArgs plugin to the modules where you want to use the navigation component and it'll automatically generate the needed files.